# Displaying Date in a TextField

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitextfield, uidatepicker

I am having a textfield which when tapped pops up a date picker and and the selected date is displayed in the textfield.

my problem is i want todays date to be displayed in the textfield by default before the user tap the textfield. later the user can change it by tapping and selecting someother date according to his requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I got your idea correctly, you need to use placeholder property of the textfield

```
NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate: [NSDate date]];
textField.placeholder = dateString;
```

Placeholder value will be displayed in textfield, while it's value is empty.

Answer (score 3):

Take the date and assign it to the textField.text and again when user picks the value then again change the value of textField.text

```
   NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"hh:mma dd/MMM"];
NSString *dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:today];
NSLog(@"date: %@", dateString);
[dateFormat release];
 textField.text = dateString;
```

If you have pickerview of dates then in respective function 
assign the selected value to textField.text
Thats it.

Comment: Where is that today declared?

Comment: NSDate *today = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0];

Comment: @Abc: what about `[NSDate date];`? That would be sufficient I guess.

Comment: @7KV7: yes, thats also sufficient. This is just an alternative to show date. if he wants to show the time also then the way I wrote is perfect but you are right he just wants date then your way is enough.

Comment: Not quite correct: [NSDate date] has full current time value, not just the date, so will alway be better than dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:

Answer (score 3):

You can use like this..

```
textfield.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[NSDate date]];
```

or

```
textField.placeholder=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[NSDate date]];
```

When the UITextfield value Empty (**textfield by default before the user tap the textfield**), the placeholder value will display.

Comment: You should always use a dateFormatter (-1); but +1 for suggesting placeholder.

Answer (score 0):

Todays date can be obtained by `NSDate *today = [NSDate date];` Assign the string from this `NSDate` object to your text field. The string can be obtained using `NSDateFormatter`.